# Input-field: pre-filled value not deletable, but extendable

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

As I'm not that familiar with JavaScript, I did some research around the web to have sth. to go on, but was not able to solve my problem.

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wf9zX/) to show you how it shall look like.
Well, my problem is that the light-grey pre-filled value "E-Mail" shall not be deletable, but the value itself shall be extendable in black font color.

Have you got an idea how to make it happen?

Thank you.

Comment: "but the value itself shall be extendable in black font color."
what do u mean by this??

Comment: Hi, like E-Mail as the prefilled value + some text the user types. ->[grey & not deletable]E-Mail[/][black & deletable]some Text[/]

Comment: did u mean both in one text box.?

Comment: You can't have differently-styled text within an input element, since it has no capacity to contain elements, and works poorly, if at all, with pseudo-elements (`::before` and `::after`).

Comment: @Philemon philip Kunjumon: That's exactly what I meant. Thank you.

Comment: @David Thomas: So there is no way to make one part not deleteable and the other one deletable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/wf9zX/2/

use lable for that input field and concat input field value and lable text

Comment: Aw. Thank you. I was looking for sth. like that.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Why wouldn't you use two inputs styled differently ? You can disable or make the first one readonly and still concat both input POST values.

I don't think styling INSIDE an input is very W3C friendly.

**Solution 2**

Use a background image (an image where "E-mail" is written) in your input with some padding-left. The when you get the POSt value, just add the string "E-mail" to it. It's like they do cutom search button icons on inputs.

See the new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gxY5P/4/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. Solution 1 sounds better to me. I'll get back to you as soon as possible.

Comment: No problem. Although i'd use solution 2 ! ;)

Comment: Yeah, normally I'd go for it, but unfortunately I cannot implement any graphics ;-)

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you. If I had some reputation, as soon as I have enough reputation I vote your answer up.